# Restrict placement of composite-component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

Is it possible to declare a composite-component in such a way that it can just be placed inside certain tags?

E.g that:

```
<span>
    <n:myComponent/>
</span>
```

would be illegal, while:

```
<div>
    <n:myComponent/>
</div>
```

would be legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not during buildtime, but during rendertime you could check the siblings of the component.

```
public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) {
    List<UIComponent> children = getParent().getChildren();
    // Loop over children until you find a child which equals to "this".
    // Then check if the previous and next sibling contains <span> and </span>.
    // ...

    if (valid) {
        super.encodeChildren(context);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n:myComponent can't be placed inside <span>");
    }
}
```

You can do this in an `UINamingContainer` implementation which is as `@FacesComponent` referenced by `<cc:interface componentType>`.

Comment: Couldnt I check against `getParent()` directly?

Comment: No, the `getParent()` is the closest parent `UIComponent` instance. The `<div>` and `<span>` are not fullworthy `UIComponents`, but just treated as plain text. They appear as siblings of the same parent `UIComponent`. If it were an `<h:panelGroup><n:myComponent/></h:panelGroup>`, then you would indeed get the `<h:panelGroup>` by `getParent()`.

Comment: Oh, I wasnt aware of the fact that `<div>` and `<span>` are treaten as plain text. I used them for demonstration purpose. Actually I want to check whether Im a child of `<p:panelGrid>` of the Primefaces component library. I guess `<p:panelGrid>` is a `UIComponent` so checking against `getParent()` should work.